# Excluding xpath elements that have children with certain value

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<LowestOfferListings>
    <LowestOfferListing>
      <Qualifiers>
        <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
        <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
        <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
        <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
        <ShippingTime>
          <Max>0-2 days</Max>
        </ShippingTime>
        <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>95-97%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
      </Qualifiers>
      <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>5</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
      <SellerFeedbackCount>9197</SellerFeedbackCount>
      <Price>
        <LandedPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>JPY</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>1675.00</Amount>
        </LandedPrice>
        <ListingPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>JPY</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>1275.00</Amount>
        </ListingPrice>
        <Shipping>
          <CurrencyCode>JPY</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>400.00</Amount>
        </Shipping>
      </Price>
      <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
    </LowestOfferListing>
    <LowestOfferListing>
      <Qualifiers>
        <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
        <ItemSubcondition>New</ItemSubcondition>
        <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
        <ShipsDomestically>False</ShipsDomestically>
        <ShippingTime>
          <Max>0-2 days</Max>
        </ShippingTime>
        <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>90-94%</SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
      </Qualifiers>
      <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>3</NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
      <SellerFeedbackCount>1430</SellerFeedbackCount>
      <Price>
        <LandedPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>JPY</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>1820.00</Amount>
        </LandedPrice>
        <ListingPrice>
          <CurrencyCode>JPY</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>1240.00</Amount>
        </ListingPrice>
        <Shipping>
          <CurrencyCode>JPY</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>580.00</Amount>
        </Shipping>
      </Price>
      <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
    </LowestOfferListing>
</LowestOfferListings>
```

I'm trying to get a count of all `LowestOfferListing` elements that have `ShipsDomestically='False'` while ignoring any namespace constraints.

This would get me a count of all of the listings:

```
count(//*[local-name()='LowestOfferListing'])
```

How would I filter out those with the child element?

I tried these, but they do not work:

```
count(//*[local-name()='LowestOfferListing']/descendant::*[not(ShipsDomestically='False')])
count(//*[local-name()='LowestOfferListing'][not(ShipsDomestically='False')])
count(//*[local-name()='LowestOfferListing'][not(local-name()='ShipsDomestically'='False')])
```

Comment: Why are you ignoring namespace constraints? Just handle the namespaces properly.

Comment: @JLRishe This is a snippet from an MWS response. Some of the responses use multiple namespaces for different child elements, which can make portability for the Xpaths between methods a bit tricky. I've found in many cases it is just easier to ignore the namespaces in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
count(//*[local-name()='LowestOfferListing' and descendant::ShipsDomestically = 'False'])
```

Comment: This works with a slight modification for namespace: `count(//*[local-name()='LowestOfferListing' and descendant::*[local-name()='ShipsDomestically'] = 'True'])`